# Standard keyboard shortcut for "About"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a standard keyboard shortcut for the "About" window / menu item?

If not, what are the most widely used shortcuts for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

then,

<kbd>a</kbd>

That's the simplest I can think of. I use it often.